# Flask-Admin deleting secondary mapping on update

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask, flask-admin

I'm using Flask-Admin and when I update my content object, it deletes all the items in its associated lookup table (content_products_table).

So if I have a Content object and 7 products mapped in its lookup table (content_products_table) all the mapping from the content to the product is deleted when its updated.

I believe this is happening because my products list is empty while its updating, but in reality my product list could be 1000 items long so I wouldn't want to load it before updating, just simply not update it at all.  I feel like there is a way to configure Flask-Admin or sqlalchemy to ignore the field on update.

Example my object below:

```
content_products_table = db.Table('content_products', db.Model.metadata,
                       db.Column('content_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('content.id')),
                       db.Column('product_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('product.id'))
                       )

class Content(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    products = db.relationship('Product', secondary=content_products_table)
```

Example of the code thats updating my object:

```
form.populate_obj(model)
self._on_model_change(form, model, False)
self.session.commit()
```

Any information would help since I'm new to both of these platforms. Thanks!

**EDIT**

I wanted to update that when my objects are updated, it deletes all relationships.  So if I have a table User who has a One To Many to a table Content.  The user_id will be set to null in the Content table when I update the User.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

form_excluded_columns = ('products')

Need to explicitly exclude object properties.  This seems very dangerous.

Comment: That's very strange. Flask-Admin calls SQLAlchemy `delete` method on a model and SQLAlchemy does deletion. It does not do anything extra. So, if related models are getting deleted, then you configured relations that way and SQLAlchemy is cleaning everything up. Showing or hiding the column won't make any difference.